# C# abstract Dispose method

Tags: c#, abstract-class, dispose, static-analysis

I have an abstract class that implements IDisposable, like so:

```
public abstract class ConnectionAccessor : IDisposable
{
    public abstract void Dispose();
}
```

In Visual Studio 2008 Team System, I ran Code Analysis on my project and one of the warnings that came up was the following:

> Microsoft.Design : Modify 'ConnectionAccessor.Dispose()' so that it calls Dispose(true), then calls GC.SuppressFinalize on the current object instance ('this' or 'Me' in Visual Basic), and then returns.

Is it just being silly, telling me to modify the body of an abstract method, or should I do something further in any derived instance of `Dispose`?

Comment: Why do you need to add Dispose() to your interface? If it is inherited from IDisposable the Dispose() method is already part of your interface.

Comment: Seth, you have to implement all interface members. Leaving it out wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should follow the conventional pattern for implementing `Dispose`. Making `Dispose()` virtual is considered bad practice, because the conventional pattern emphasizes reuse of code in "managed cleanup" (API client calling `Dispose()` directly or via `using`) and "unmanaged cleanup" (GC calling finalizer). To remind, the pattern is this:

```
public class Base
{
    ~Base()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // so that Dispose(false) isn't called later
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
             // Dispose all owned managed objects
        }

        // Release unmanaged resources
    }
}
```

Key here is that there's no duplication between finalizer and `Dispose` for unmanaged cleanup, and yet any derived class can extend both managed and unmanaged cleanup.

For your case, what you should do is this:

```
protected abstract void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

and leave everything else as is. Even that is of dubious value, since you're enforcing your derived classes to implement `Dispose` now - and how do you know that all of them need it? If your base class has nothing to dispose, but most derived classes likely do (with a few exceptions, perhaps), then just provide an empty implementation. It is what `System.IO.Stream` (itself abstract) does, so there is precedent.

Comment: I'd much rather people were advised to do this: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-implement-idisposable-and.html - the pattern would be a hell of a lot simpler if it didn't have built-in support for classes that mix managed & unmanaged resources.

Comment: If any class derived from a particular class will need to implement IDisposable, and if an object which expects to be given a base-class type may end up holding the last useful reference to it, the base class should implement IDisposable, even if the vast majority of derived classes won't need it.

Comment: Isn't this pattern outdated since .net 2? My understanding is that the unmanaged resources should be held by some form of safehandle/critical handle and normal user implemented classes don't need a finalizer anymore. And their `Dispose` just calls `Dispose` on the handle.

Answer (score 10):

The warning basically tells you to implement the [**Dispose pattern**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) in your class.

The resulting code should look like this:

```
public abstract class ConnectionAccessor : IDisposable
{
    ~ConnectionAccessor()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the pattern, and pointing out that the Dispose(bool) should be the virtual/abstract method that derived classes should implement or override, not Dispose().

Answer (score 5):

While it does seem a little like nit-picking, the advice is valid.  You are already indicating that you expect any sub-types of ConnectionAccessor will have *something* that they need to dispose.  Therefore, it does seem better to ensure that the proper cleanup is done (in terms of the GC.SuppressFinalize call) by the base class rather than relying on each subtype to do it.

I use the dispose pattern mentioned in Bruce Wagners book [Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660) which is basically:

```
public class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed = false;
    ~BaseClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            //release managed resources
        }

        //release unmanaged resources

        _disposed = true;
    }
}

public void Derived : BaseClass
{
    private bool _disposed = false;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) 
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            //release managed resources
        }

        //release unmanaged resources

        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _disposed = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The only gripe I'd have with the answers provided so far is that they all assume that you **need** to have a finalizer, which isn't necessarily the case.  There is a fairly significant performance overhead associated with finalization, which I wouldn't want to impose on all of my derived classes if it wasn't necessary.

See [this blog post](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae) by Joe Duffy, which explains when you may or may not need a finalizer, and how to properly implement the Dispose pattern in either case.
Summarizing Joe's blog post, unless you're doing something fairly low-level dealing with unmanaged memory, you shouldn't implement a finalizer.  As a general rule of thumb, if your class only holds references to managed types that implement IDisposable themselves, you don't need the finalizer (but should implement IDisposable and dispose of those resources).  If you are allocating unmanaged resources directly from your code (PInvoke?) and those resources must be freed, you need one.  A derived class can always add a finalizer if it really needs it, but forcing all derived classes to have a finalizer by putting it in the base class causes all derived classes to be impacted by the performance hit of finalizable objects when that overhead may not be necessary.

Comment: My favourite gripe. Most people just don't bother trying to understand this, and the best advice they tend to get is to just implement the Microsoft pattern. Here's what I think is much better advice than the "official" pattern: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-implement-idisposable-and.html

Comment: That is indeed a good blog post on the subject - simple and too the point.

Answer (score -1):

The warning is interesting though. Eric Lippert, one of the C# designers, blogged about why error messages should be "Diagnostic but not prescriptive: describe the problem, not the solution".
[Read here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/07/07/error-messages-diagnostic-is-preferable-to-prescriptive.aspx)

Comment: It's not a compiler error message. It's the result of running a tool that specifically points out problematic things. There's nothing wrong with it also pointing out the solution.

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to share the link. It came to me because the message doesn't state the problem but gives the solution only. Hopefully there was a previous message doing that.

Comment: This is kind of tangential to the original question.